# SQL -Create table if not exists, and insert value

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I check my SQL database to see if a column exists if not create, but I wanted to insert a string in that column, but only if the column didn´t exist.
Otherwise I handle that information in my C# code.
So far I have this code :

```
string query = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tabela' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'coluna') ALTER TABLE tabela ADD coluna varchar(50)" ;  
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How should I do ?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: It works ok ! I just needed to add the update to the database inserting a string in the just created column.

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value);

This is more of a SQL Question than C#. You didn't have to provide any C# code really.

Comment: I think it's better you create a procedure which will handle all these and call that procedure from your code. Your sql code will be manageable in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to execute a block after the IF  (psuedocode):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(...)
  BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE MyTable ...;
  INSERT INTO MyTable ...;
  END
```

Be sure to put semicolons at the end of the ALTER and INSERT commands, since you are sending these in a single command from an application, so SQL Server will see them as being all on one line.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a `trigger` for each SELECT from the database object. In that you can first check if the column exists, and then you can do the needful. This you can achieve entirely by using SQL triggres (or even stored procedures
), C# has nothing to do with it :)

For more details on triggers, you can check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799.aspx) out

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think there's any such thing as a SELECT TRIGGER in SQL Server.